# How do I force Zend to use hyphens instead of camel case urls for two word controller names?

Tags: regex, zend-framework, url, routes

Zend allows me to use both

```
    http://localhost/controllerName
    http://localhost/controller-name
```

Instead I'd like to make all controllers use hyphens and redirect to this version

example:

```
    localhost/big-widget
    localhost/big-red-widget
```

I don't want to set them on an individual basis.

I couldn't find any useful tutorials on this, I'd appreciate any help!

I did look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html
and some other posts, but I didn't see anything that I could understand easily.

Thanks

Comment: How does controllerName and controller-name relate to big-widget and big-red-widget. Please add more information to your question so I can understand it better.

Comment: "I don't want to set them on an individual basis." What are you setting on individual basis?

Comment: I guess you just have to name your actions 'mySampleAction()' in your controller. This will turn out to be 'controllername/my-sample'

Answer (score 1):

I think by default Zend Framework already uses hyphens instead of camel casing .

**Example:** If you have your controller class `UserControlController` then it automatically uses `user-control` for the URL and does the same for action `userLoginAction` uses `user-login` in URL. Like this

> http://myapp.com/user-control/user-login/